# EF: Get master-detail based on conditions on master as well as on detail

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

EF Core 3.1 and such master-detail model:

```cs
public class MyMaster
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<MyDetail> MyDetails { get; set; }
}

public class MyDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid MasterId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to select all master records in certain category together with details not marked as deleted. Also if all details for particular master are marked as deleted then this master is not returned. Basically I'd like to run such simple select:

```sql
select * from MyMaster m
inner join MyDetail d on m.Id = d.MasterId and d.IsDeleted = 0
where m.Category = 'foo'
```

I try such LINQ method, but it returns also deleted detail records:

```cs
var result = await dbContext.MyMasters
    .Include(m => m.MyDetails)
    .Where(m => m.Category = 'foo')
    .Join(dbContext.MyDetails.Where(d => !d.IsDeleted), m => m.Id, d => d.MasterId, (m, d) => m)
    .ToListAsync();
```

How the LINQ method query should look like?

Comment: Have you read [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes, but in this particular case I'd like to know how to write it in LINQ.

Comment: With `Include` it is possible only in EF Core 5. But you can construct LINQ query without include.

Comment: When `Include` is missing then the final result does not contain any detail records.

Comment: Do you need final result for modification? Or just for query?

Comment: Just for query, I did not put `AsNoTracking` into the example above for simplicity.

Comment: @PetrFelzmann Why are you using `Join` at all? If you want to filter the related entities (there's no master/detail in entities and objects), you can use [filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) in EF Core 5 and later, ie `.Include(m => m.MyDetails.Where(d=>!d.IsDeleted))`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because, as I wrote in question, EF 3.1.

Comment: @PetrFelzmann you don't need JOINs in any EF version. I already answered how to use query filters in EF Core 2 and later

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Query filters were suggested in the very first comment in this thread. And, as I immediately answered, I wanted to solve it w/o query filters, just with plain LINQ query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need data just for query, it can be easily retrieved by `Select`:

```cs
var result = await dbContext.MyMasters
    .Where(m => m.Category = 'foo')
    .Select(m => new MyMaster
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Category = m.Category,
        MyDetails = m.MyDetails.Where(d => !d.IsDeleted).ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: BTW the needed mapping to achieve the solution of such basic task is pretty ugly, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Actually `Include` for me is bad way to retrieve data for DTO object. With `Select` you can control returned data from database up to single field.

Comment: ORM should be able to return the model w/o such manual mapping. Pity it was added to EF so late (v5).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the actual question is how to filter the related entities.

**Filtered Includes**

In EF Core 5 and later this is done using [filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include):

```
var result = await dbContext.MyMasters
    .Include(m => m.MyDetails.Where(d=>!d.IsDeleted))
    .Where(m => m.Category = 'foo')
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Global Query Filters**

In EF Core 2 and late another option is to use [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to ensure deleted entities are never loaded through that DbContext, even by accident :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyDetail>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
    ...
}
```

This way, the following query will only load active records :

```
var result = await dbContext.MyMasters
    .Include(m => m.MyDetails)
    .Where(m => m.Category = 'foo')
    .ToListAsync();
```

A global query filter affects the entire DbContext which is *perfectly fine*. A DbContext isn't a model of the database, and entities aren't tables. It's perfectly fine to have different DbContexts with entities and different configurations targeting the same database, that handle specific scenarios/use cases (bounded contexts if you like DDD).

In this case most of the application would use a DbContext with the global query filter(s) while administrative pages would use a different one that allowed access to all records

Answer (score 0):

Your code is true bro, but I write and tested these queries and shown the result. its worked for me.

```
         var result = await _dBContext.MyMasters
            .Include(m => m.MyDetails)
            .Where(m => m.Category == "foo")
            .Join(_dBContext.MyDetails.Where(d => !d.IsDeleted),
                m => m.Id,
                d => d.MasterId,
                (m, d) => new {
                    MasterId = m.Id,
                    Category = m.Category,
                    DetailId = d.Id,
                    IsDeleted = d.IsDeleted,
                })
            .ToListAsync();


        var result2 = from m in _dBContext.MyMasters.Include(m => m.MyDetails)
                      join d in _dBContext.MyDetails on m.Id equals d.MasterId
                      where m.Category == "foo" && !d.IsDeleted
                      select new { 
                            MasterId = m.Id,
                            Category = m.Category,
                            DetailId = d.Id,  
                            IsDeleted = d.IsDeleted,
                      };
```

[image]

> you try for select New type after Join two collection. IF you get Collection from MyDetails in masters, you have all items because it's not filtered, it's just all navigations item.

Comment: I'd like to achieve it without specifying anonymous type.

Comment: anonymous type are not important, your  result of  join should be in one type. if you just select Master, You will have duplicate items, and have invalid items in master navigations property.